# Image onload not being called in vue

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I am trying to build a Vue App and I am new to Vue, I am trying to load an image at runtime in Js/Ts with the code below

```
console.log("code is being called");
let image = new Image();
image.onload = (event) => {
console.log("image loaded");
}
image.src = "static/prison_tileset.png";
```

The code works fine on a regular html file, in Vue however, the onload method isn't being called. The first console.log is being called. I am sure that the image is found because if I manipulate the path to something wrong on purpose I get an error that the file isn't being found. It's just that the onload event isn't being firied.

I'd be very happy if somebody could help me with that!

Comment: I am not mounting it to the DOM yet, as far as I know onload is suppoed to be called when the image is done being loaded (it also works just fine when I run the code without vue as stated in my post)

Comment: The goal is to load the image at runtime and draw it on a canvas, I don't know which image to draw at compile time

Comment: yeah, makes sense, my bad.
can you create a codesandbox/fiddle/stackblitz to recreate the issue ?

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to import the project into stackbliz but I have logged the onerror event, and apparantly it says "permission denied"

Answer (score 1):

I've gotten it to work now! I will answer the question myself as best as I can. To use local assets in view you have to load them via Webpack like this:

```
const Logo = require("../assets/logo.png");
this.image.src = Logo;
```

If you also happen to use electron you have to set the webSecurity in your entry file to false for electron to be allowed to access local files.